# Returning html in route in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, routes, render

I am trying to return html in my flask file but I cant see anything in the webview. Is there something wrong with my views, main, init or html file It isn't mandatory to use blocks right?

Thanks.

**views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

views = Blueprint("views", __name__)

@views.route('/views')
def home():
    return render_template('base.html')
```

**main.py**

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET KEY'] = 'Moneyteam'

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    return app
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ticks - Luxury Watch Marketplace</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ticks</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      
      <main>
        <section id="hero">
          <h2>Welcome to Ticks</h2>
          <p>Discover the finest luxury watches in the world</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
        </section>
        
        <section id="products">
          <h2>Featured Products</h2>
          <div class="product">
            <img src="watch1.jpg" alt="Luxury Watch 1">
            <h3>Luxury Watch 1</h3>
            <p>$999.99</p>
          </div>
          <div class="product">
            <img src="watch2.jpg" alt="Luxury Watch 2">
            <h3>Luxury Watch 2</h3>
            <p>$1499.99</p>
          </div>
          <div class="product">
            <img src="watch3.jpg" alt="Luxury Watch 3">
            <h3>Luxury Watch 3</h3>
            <p>$1999.99</p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2022 Ticks - Luxury Watch Marketplace. All rights reserved.</p>
      </footer>
      
      <!--<script type="text/javascript"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js'')}}">
      </script> -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

I hoped to see a returned website. I am expecting to have to use blocks to customize each different page but I'd like to know what im doing wrong as of right now first. I am a beginnner, sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your app routes are the same "/" if you change them like below you can access the right views:

```
app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/views')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/auth')
```

You can try to connect to http://localhost:8000/views or /auth

And also your secret key variable is wrong, use this instead:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Moneyteam'
```

Comment: Thankyou, still can't make it work but I'll try something else